# JSON Slow Loading in Node App

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, ibm-cloud

After reviewing my load waterfall, I'm noticing that my local JSON files are loading 2 - 3 seconds after my parallel loading JS. Does asynchronous file load solve this issue (I need to check) or is there something else I'm missing?

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get('/example0', function(req,res) {
  var json = require('./json/example0.json');
  res.send(json.factors);
});

app.get('/example1', function(req,res) {
  var json = require('./json/example1.json');
  res.send(json.data);
})

app.get('/example3', function(req,res) {
  var json = require('./json/example3.json');
  res.send(json.matches);
})

app.post('/parse', function (req, res) {
  req.session.user = cleanTextProfile(req.body);
  return res.json(req.session.user);
});
```

I renamed the files for privacy purposes. These are the lines that reference json loading.

Comment: More details would be better for your question....

Comment: Please add some code to help us help you. A minimal, complete and verifiable example would be great: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Async can only help if your program can handle it.